# How does aesthetic relate to structure?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, aesthetics, art

If we are to take a subject say mathematics, then often mathematicians may attribute to the well defined structure and precision in describing its theories. I believe there are also other things like architecture, body building etc where structure plays a strong role in aesthetic.

But take for example literal art, say a painting by a skilled painter. Then a person looking at the picture may feel a sense of aesthetic allure to it even if they can't give a description of its structure confidently.

And finally take a painter who is only a beginner, they may draw something on a whim which has no clear structure just like the professional painter yet a person viewing the art may not derive the same sense of aesthetic allure they found from viewing the painting of the skilled painter.

Due to these examples giving conflicting suggestions on how to abstract the relation between aesthetic and structure, I am torn.

Could someone explain eloquently what exactly the relation between the ideas of aesthetic and structure are? Thanks.

Comment: Humans are drawn to things with good form. They are attracted to symmetrical faces. These things represent health and vitality. When an artist can be innovative yet still include a reassuring sense of order, we like that.

Comment: Indeed this is such a deep and important topic in philosophy that Kant dedicated a significant section called *transcendental aesthetics* of his famous CPR to delve into its stated aim to present a “science of all principles of a priori sensibility” even more important than his another section called *transcendental logic*. From model theory we know the really interesting and deeper part of symbolic logic is actually about algebraic structures which is in turn actually about Kant's transcendental aesthetics which is in turn actually related to (virtue) ethics of the good...